# How to calculate bounty prize for 1-st place?

Tags: tournament, online, mtt

I try to calculate bounty prize for 1-st place in standard structures of bounty MTT. I observed ~10 tournaments, where I can see player who won tournament, he received ~20%-25% of bounty prize pool. How to calculate it correct?

For example, if prize pool is $100000, and bounty prize pool is $100000, player who wins is tournament received ~$20-$25K?

Sorry for English, I speak English very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to really calculate this, just estimate it based on observation. If you win the tournament you are for sure going to win one bounty(that for busting the player winning second place). Besides that everything else is variable. You could win without collecting all but the one bounty. It is likely that if you do win you will also have won a lot of bounties, it just not easy to say how many with any reliability.